# interval reduce the font-size of text in CSS

Tags: css

My problem is that i want to reduce the font size by 10% every 2 seconds

```
<div class="reduce"> text </div>

.reduce{
transition: 2s linear all;
font-size : 20px;
}
```

how can I do it with css only?

Comment: Reduce by 10% till when? Till it reaches 0? 10% of original size or the size  after each reduction? And when should the reduction happen (on hover or on page load?)

Comment: @GolezTrol: That could have a lot of meanings. "every 2 seconds" could be "every 2 seconds while hover is on" or "every 2 seconds after page load" or "every 2 seconds after a click on the body/div" etc.

Comment: Or every 2 seconds while the moon is full or every 2 seconds if it's the third tab in the browser. Since there is no mention of hover or any kind of special event or condition, let's just assume every 2 seconds when the user actually has this page open, or, if you want some flexibility: every 2 seconds while this 'reduce' class exists on the element.

Comment: till I press on button for stop

Comment: Assumptions doesn't make a good question @GolezTrol. I would rather await clarification than post an answer only for it to become invalidated after an edit. (*Edit:* And there you go, have a look at the previous comment :))

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is by css animations:

```css
div {

    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 15s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 15s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;/*leaves properties at values from the end of animation*/
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {font-size: 20px;}
    100% {font-size: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {font-size: 20px;}
    100% {font-size: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
```

Font size changes linearly.
In case you want those changes to occur in different steps you could set them to some specific values:

```
@keyframes example {
    0%   {font-size: 20px;}
    10%   {font-size: 18px;}
    20%  {font-size: 17px;}
   30%   {font-size: 16px;}
/* etc...*/
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a `css` only solution, but with a few lines of `jquery` you can make it work. You have to set an interval and use two different functions to change `font-size` after a certain amount of time.

```
var textuptimer = setInterval(textup, 1000);
function textup() {
    $(".heart").css("font-size", "1em");
}

var textdowntimer = setInterval(textdown, 2000);
function textdown() {
    $(".heart").css("font-size", "0.8em");
}
```

**[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/45a1muek/)** is a working fiddle.